# OneNote VSTO gone?

Tags: c#, vsto, add-on, onenote

I want to create a project related to OneNote add-on, however when I check into project templates I did not see a project template for OneNote 2013 Add-on. Is there a way I could develop an add-on for OneNote since Microsoft removed it from VSTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very helpful tutorial for anyone looking for a guide on how to create an add-in for OneNote. Thanks to the author of Onetastic for Microsoft OneNote ([Onetastic Add-in](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/)) in sharing this guide. Here is the link for the guide: [Creating OneNote Add-ins](http://www.malteahrens.com/#/blog/howto-onenote-dev/). This guide is very informative.

Comment: The link is no longer available, but i recommend this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/onenote-quickstart

Answer (score 3):

VSTO [does not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942839.aspx) creating addins for OneNote. You can crate an addin for OneNote in a slightly different way though. You need to implement the IRibbonExtensibility interface as noted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed366aa2-131d-450f-aec8-e123409a29e9/onenote-2010-ribbon-addin?forum=innovateonoffice).

Comment: sorry I'm just new in developing software. Add-ons and Add-ins are two different thing.

Comment: Ah, maybe my response wasn't clear enough. Addins and addons are the same thing. It seems I used both terms and confused you. What I meant to say was: you cannot create an OneNote addin with VSTO, but you can do it in a different way. More about it is explained on that second link I posted. I slightly updated the answer so that it is a bit more clear.