# Create Ribbon for OneNote 2013 32bit and 64bit

Tags: add-in, ribbon, onenote

I would like to create a Ribbon for OneNote. 
Like the Onenote Add-In "Onetastic".

I have tried the following tutorial:
("Developing OneNote 2010 Add‐Ins")
http://www.malteahrens.com/#/blog/howto-onenote-dev/
... but without success :(

Does anyone have a hint what I have to change for developing an OneNote Add-in for OneNote 2013 32bit & 64 bit

Background:
I would create a simple button to call an external webpage (via URL) which is located in a ribbon. Like a simple "favourite"-Button

Would be nice :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [OneNote VSTO gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463514/onenote-vsto-gone) page first.

The [How to develop an OneNote 2010 ribbon add-in application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2555352) article includes a code sample which demonstrates how to develop a Microsoft OneNote COM add-in application that implements the IRibbonExtensibility interface. The code sample also introduces how to use the OneNote object model.