# Developer Tab Not Showing in Microsoft Onenote

Tags: vba, onenote

For some reason a user is not able to display the developer tab to **OneNote** (2016 -- [see specific version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnz21.png))

The developer checkbox is not appearing when clicking customize the ribbon (see below).

- No add-ins installed.
- User can add developer to other MS products like Word and Excel.
- Tried reset customization of Main Tabs.
- User should have admin rights.

  *Any idea why this might be or how to resolve?*

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: There's no VBA in OneNote. Maybe start [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/onenote). Great opportunity to learn Office Add-Ins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote is not a VBA host application, so it doesn't have a Developer tab.

Other options for OneNote automation include:

- [Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/onenote/) and the Office JavaScript API.
- Perhaps the approach discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463514/onenote-vsto-gone) (untested in the latest version of OneNote)